# Custom view for swift

Tags: xcode, listview, swift3

I want to make an view that looks like a wall in swift 3.
Here is an example:
[image]

Every entry should look like a square with some information.

Is there any framework which I can use or do someone know a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment because of reputation issue. You can use UICollectionView if every entry has same width and height.Here is a tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started.

If not, you can create subviews using UIView with your desired UI components.